# Modal no abre al dar click en FullCalendar Laravel 8

Tags: modal, laravel-8, fullcalendar, bootstrap-5

El problema que tengo es sencillo y en cada tutorial que veo de como usan FullCalendar empiezo a seguir el paso a paso pero no puedo continuar de donde se añade el modal para ingresar la información, tengo los CDN de bootstrap y de jquery y supuestamente solo es añadir al select: function() esto $("#example_modal").modal(); pero no me funciona. Tengo ese código en un archivo index con un section que se extiende de layouts.app y en este archivo tengo los CDN, bueno de hecho lo tengo en los dos ya que parece que no me reconociera el bootstrap porque al darle click no pasa nada.

index

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card" style="left: 125px; bottom: 11px;">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Agenda') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body" id="calendar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="agenda_modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection

@section('css')
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='{{ asset("fullcalendar/main.css")}}' rel='stylesheet' />
@endsection

@section('js')

<script src='{{ asset("fullcalendar/main.js")}}'></script>
<script src='{{ asset("fullcalendar/locales/es.js")}}'></script>



<script>
    $(function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            locale: 'es',
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            select: function(arg) {
                console.log(arg);
                $("#agenda_modal").modal();
                calendar.unselect()
            },
            eventClick: function(arg) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
                    arg.event.remove()
                }
            },
            editable: true,
        });

        calendar.render();
    })
</script>
@endsection
```

layouts.app

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CoreUI for Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@4.1.1/dist/css/coreui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    @yield('css')

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
</head>

<body>
    @include('partials.menu')
    <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-light">
        <header class="header header-sticky mb-4" style="background-color:#358180 ;">

        </header>
        <div class="body flex-grow-1 px-3">
            <div class="container-lg">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div><a href="https://coreui.io">CoreUI </a><a href="https://coreui.io">Bootstrap Admin Template</a> © 2021 creativeLabs.</div>
        <div class="ms-auto">Powered by&nbsp;<a href="https://coreui.io/bootstrap/ui-components/">CoreUI UI Components</a></div>
    </footer>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: CoreUI for Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@4.1.1/dist/js/coreui.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    @yield('js')


    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and CoreUI for Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@4.1.1/dist/js/coreui.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
    <script>
        function CerrarSesion() {
            event.preventDefault();
            Swal.fire({
                title: "¿Desea cerrar sesión?",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#2eb85c',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, cerrar sesión!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si es frustante que no funcione en ocasiones,  checa este enlace te va a dar un norte de la estructura del fullcalendar https://programacion.net/articulo/como_integrar_el_plugin_fullcalendar_de_jquery_con_bootstrap-_php_y_mysql_1679     Analizarlo debes, por que creo que te faltan segmentos de código que integran los modales.